# VBA: Excel Scatter Graph Animation with Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a personal investment tracking workbook where I have scatter graphs of my accounts comparing their performance to different indices over time.  I wanted to animate plotting of the points showing the comparative performance over time.  I borrowed a macro subroutine to do this from another users group site and am trying to implement it.

I have one COMPARISON worksheet (`Sheet3`) with the charts on it, with account and index data on other worksheets (`Sheet2`, `Sheet4`, ...).  I would later attach this to a button next to the chart to launch it.  This subroutine will work (without the `"Sheet2!"` in the `Range` statements) on the chart when it is on the same worksheet as the data but when I move it to the COMPARISON worksheet it will not work.  I keep getting the

> "Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed"

error no matter how I construct the range syntax string.
Here is the non-working code:

```
Public Sub AnimateChart1()
  Dim rX As Range
  Dim rY As Range
  Dim x As Long
  Dim chtObj As ChartObject
  Dim dWait As Double

  'change as desired
  Set chtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart1") 'chartname
  Set rX = Range("Sheet2!J116:J340") 'X-range
  Set rY = Range("Sheet2!G116:G340") 'Y-range
  dWait = TimeValue("0:00:01") '1 sec wait

  For x = 1 To rX.Rows.Count
    With chtObj.Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
      .XValues = rX.Resize(x)
      .Values = rY.Resize(x)
      Application.Wait (Now + dWait)
    End With
  Next
End Sub
```

The `"Run-time error '1004'"` occurs on Code Line 9 with the `"Set rX = ..."` and I am sure it would not work on Code Line 10 with the `"Set rY = ..."`.  I have tried all permutations of a valid excel link string with many producing compile time errors in Excel debugger.  It looks like the Range object/function/statement is being used to convert the worksheet range string to an actual range and I have not found this usage of Range around much.

I would like to keep this `Range` syntax as a string because I would later generalized the subroutine for multiple charts with arguments passed as strings for efficiently using it.  Thanks for any help in resolving this problem I am having.

Comment: I tried your code, it is working perfectly. For forcibly reproducing the error, I have to restore to a non-existing sheet Name. So kindly check for Sheet names correctly and it will zoom..

Comment: @dcayThank you. I am overwhelmed with the _beautifully engineered Animation Idea_ in your code. It is hugely suitable for presenting & explaining real data in meetings etc.

Comment: If you intend to use 'descriptive tab names' for sheets, your piece of code will work without any modification..as you _like to keep this Range syntax as a string._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Set rX = Sheet2.Range("J116:J340")
Set rY = Sheet2.Range("G116:G340")
```

Comment: Code `Set rX = Range("Sheet2!J116:J340")` working perfectly.

Comment: Let’s wait for @dcay feedback

Comment: Thanks, I put this in on Sheet3 and it does work!  I had wanted to write one subroutine with passed arguments for the particulars to make it more generalized.  With having to call out the specific sheet object is there anyway to be able to do this?  Or just plan on a separate similar macro for each chart account?

Comment: Ahmed AU, I closed and opened excel and the workbook again and the original code still does not work when trying to access data on Sheet2 to animate a chart on Sheet3.  The code DisplayName gave does work from my Sheet3 chart so it appears there is not an error in sheet names.  These are the names Excel has given my sheets and not the descriptive tab names.  Thanks.

Comment: You can have your subroutine accept a worksheet object and a string for a range address as its parameters (e.g.: Sub MySub(sht As Worksheet, xValsAddr As String, valsAddr As String)) to set wanted ranges (e.g.: Set rX = sht.Range(xValsAddr)) and which you’d call like: MySub Sheet2, "J116:J340", “G116:G340”)

Comment: Btw since my answer solved your question you may then consider marking it as accepted. Thank you

Comment: Thanks @DisplayName for the answer and comment above.  Just what I needed.